# AngularJS ng-repeat for XML attributes

Tags: javascript, xml, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

Working with my first AngularJS project and ran into an issue. I am using XML, which I successfully converted to JSON with [x2js](https://code.google.com/p/x2js/).

I just want to display the student names: "ed frank jimmy sally"

My current code just outputs "ed jimmy" because I am just accessing `student[0]._name`. How can I cycle through all the name attributes using ng-repeat?

**XML**

```
<school>
    <teacher name="williams">
        <student name="ed"/>
        <student name="frank"/>
    </teacher>
    <teacher name="ramos">
        <student name="jimmy"/>
        <student name="sally"/>
    </teacher>
</school>
```

**JSON**

```
{
    "school": {
        "__cnt": 5,
        "teacher": [
            {
                "__cnt": 6,
                "student": [
                    {
                        "__cnt": 1,
                        "_name": "ed"
                    },
                    {
                        "__cnt": 1,
                        "_name": "frank"
                    }
                ],
                "student_asArray": [
                    {
                        "__cnt": 1,
                        "_name": "ed"
                    },
                    {
                        "__cnt": 1,
                        "_name": "frank"
                    }
                ],
                "_name": "williams",
                "__text": [
                    "\n\t\t\t",
                    "\n\t\t\t",
                    "\n\t\t"
                ]
            },
            {
                "__cnt": 6,
                "student": [
                    {
                        "__cnt": 1,
                        "_name": "jimmy"
                    },
                    {
                        "__cnt": 1,
                        "_name": "sally"
                    }
                ],
                "student_asArray": [
                    {
                        "__cnt": 1,
                        "_name": "jimmy"
                    },
                    {
                        "__cnt": 1,
                        "_name": "sally"
                    }
                ],
                "_name": "ramos",
                "__text": [
                    "\n\t\t\t",
                    "\n\t\t\t",
                    "\n\t\t"
                ]
            }
        ],
        "teacher_asArray": [
            {
                "__cnt": 6,
                "student": [
                    {
                        "__cnt": 1,
                        "_name": "ed"
                    },
                    {
                        "__cnt": 1,
                        "_name": "frank"
                    }
                ],
                "student_asArray": [
                    {
                        "__cnt": 1,
                        "_name": "ed"
                    },
                    {
                        "__cnt": 1,
                        "_name": "frank"
                    }
                ],
                "_name": "williams",
                "__text": [
                    "\n\t\t\t",
                    "\n\t\t\t",
                    "\n\t\t"
                ]
            },
            {
                "__cnt": 6,
                "student": [
                    {
                        "__cnt": 1,
                        "_name": "jimmy"
                    },
                    {
                        "__cnt": 1,
                        "_name": "sally"
                    }
                ],
                "student_asArray": [
                    {
                        "__cnt": 1,
                        "_name": "jimmy"
                    },
                    {
                        "__cnt": 1,
                        "_name": "sally"
                    }
                ],
                "_name": "ramos",
                "__text": [
                    "\n\t\t\t",
                    "\n\t\t\t",
                    "\n\t\t"
                ]
            }
        ],
        "__text": [
            "\n\t\t",
            "\n\t\t",
            "\n"
        ]
    }
}
```

**HTML**

```
<body ng-app="productsApp">
    <div ng-controller="products">
        <h2 ng-repeat="product in products ">
            {{product.student[0]._name}}
        </h2>
    </div>    
</body>
```

**JS**

```
var productApp = angular.module('productsApp',[]);
productApp.factory('productFactory',function($http){
    var factory = [];
    factory.getProducts = function(){
        return $http.get("js/allProducts.xml");
    }
    return factory;
});
productApp.controller('products',function($scope,productFactory){
    $scope.products = [];
    loadProducts();
    function loadProducts(){
        productFactory.getProducts().success(function(data){
            schools = x2js.xml_str2json(data);
            console.log(schools.school.teacher);
            $scope.products =schools.school.teacher;
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: plz show converted json structure

Comment: also be careful creating global variables like you are with `schools` ... always use `var`. Need to see structure of converted data

Comment: @Rahul justed added the json.

Comment: @charlietfl just added the json structure

Comment: that's not valid structure so it's not entirely clear what is being generated. Try `console.log(JSON.stringify(schools))` and can put result into a json editor

Comment: @TyRoderick are you sure you get correct json from x2js, because when I formate json in online json formatter,I can see it's not a valid json at all

Comment: @Rahul I just updated the json on my question. Is it valid now? (sorry, i've never worked with json before, so maybe it is wrong)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just had to change my HTML to this:

```
<body ng-app="productsApp">
<div ng-controller="products">
    <div ng-repeat="product in products">
        <div ng-repeat="teacher in product.student " style="color:red;">
        {{teacher._name}}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I just didn't know how to use the nesting correctly. Thanks to everyone!

Answer (score 0):

you can do nested ng-repeats.  For example

If your data looks like this:

```
$scope.data = {  
   "school":{  
      "teacher":[  
         {  
            "student":[  
               {  
                  "_name":"ed"
               },
               {  
                  "_name":"frank"
               }
            ],
            "_name":"williams"
         },
         {  
            "student":[  
               {  
                  "_name":"jimmy"
               },
               {  
                  "_name":"sally"
               }
            ],
            "_name":"ramos"
         }
      ]
   }
};
```

You can access any property in that structure like so:

```
 <div ng-repeat="teacher in data.school" style="background: red; width: 100%">
   <div ng-repeat="students in teacher" style="background: yellow; width: 90%">    
     <!--Prints each object in the teacher array -->
     {{students}}
     <div ng-repeat="student in students" style="background: lightblue; width: 80%">      
       <!--Prints each object in the student array -->
       {{student}}
       <div ng-repeat="details in student" style="background: green; width: 80%">
         <!--Prints the name of each student -->
         {{details._name}}
       </div>
     </div>
   </div>
 </div>
```

See this plunk for an example

http://plnkr.co/edit/kXu4PEuSmCGju7mElpm2?p=preview

Comment: Thank you! Such a small change was needed, I just didn't understand how the Angular nesting worked.

Comment: No problem. It helps me to think of ng-repeat as a foreach loop where you assign a variable name to the value of the object being iterated.

Answer (score -2):

Try $index instead of 0

```
<body ng-app="productsApp">
<div ng-controller="products"><ol><h2 ng-repeat="product in products ">
    {{product.student[$index]._name}}
</div>
```

$index will give you the current index of the product.

Comment: He's not looking for the current `product` index. He's trying to access the first element of a child collection.

Comment: doesn't make sense... $index is index of parent product in products array not the children student array. This index mismatch will cause significant problems